# Splitting a question

Tags: discussion

### high level

I asked [Biblical basis for two aspects of the Gap Theory](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32914/biblical-basis-for-two-aspects-of-the-gap-theory) without realizing how complex the question would end up being.

I would like to split the question, and ask the following questions:

Q1: Using the Bible alone, argue for: Genesis 1:2 is a sub-event of Genesis 1:1

Q2: Using the Bible alone, argue for: Genesis 1:1 happened chronologically before Genesis 1:2

I am wondering what is the best way to do this.

### motivation

I believe my original question is asking about two separate things:

1) chronological ordering of Genesis 1:1 + Genesis 1:2
  2) when did Satan fall?

I would like to analyze each question separately.

### concerns:

- normally I would just delete the original question; however there's already an answer; what should be done with the original question?
- should either of the new questions have more "meat" ? the questions, as is written, seems very 'lean', but I'm not sure how to add more to either

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is already asking the second one. You can just make a second question to ask for the basis that it is a sub event.